# how to disable cache in html purifier

Tags: htmlpurifier

i follow this document on home page of HTML Purifier, but it's not word. This is my code

```
require_once 'library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier();

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core.DefinitionCache', null);
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'enduser-customize.html tutorial');
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 1);
$config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null);

$config->set('Filter.YouTube', true);

$dirty_html = $_POST['content'];

$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
```

cache file still create in library\HTMLPurifier\DefinitionCache\Serializer\HTML

Answer (score 3):

```
require_once 'path/to/html_purifier/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null);
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass $config to the HTML Purifier constructor.

Comment: u can show me example ? .. and i have problem, when i run script, i got Notice `Notice: Core.DefinitionCache is an alias, preferred directive name is Cache.DefinitionImpl in D:\UniServer\www\vidu\purifier\library\HTMLPurifier\Config.php on line 693` .. how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have already found the solution but still want to answer for whom who still doing this mistake

```
require_once 'library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core.DefinitionCache', null);
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'enduser-customize.html tutorial');
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 1);
$config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null);

$config->set('Filter.YouTube', true);

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$dirty_html = $_POST['content'];

$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
```